# Correct use of WebSecurity in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot

In my **Spring Boot** application based on version *1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT*, I have the static resources (images, css, js) in the `static` folder under `resources`.

I see some examples related to security configuration like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/static/**");
    }
}
```

Is that example correct? 
What should be the effect? 
How to verify that it works (e.g. doing a request to `localhost:8080/something`? 
What cool things can I do with `WebSecurity`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your example means that Spring (Web) Security is [ignoring](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring()) URL patterns that match the expression you have defined `("/static/**")`. This URL is skipped by Spring Security, therefore not secured.

> Allows adding RequestMatcher instances that should that Spring Security should ignore. Web Security provided by Spring Security (including the SecurityContext) will not be available on HttpServletRequest that match. Typically the requests that are registered should be that of only static resources. For requests that are dynamic, consider mapping the request to allow all users instead.

See [WebSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html) API documentation for more info.

You can have as many URL patterns secured or unsecured as you want.
With Spring Security you have *authentication* and *access control* features for the web layer of an application. You can also restrict users who have a specified role to access a particular URL and so on.

Read the Spring Security reference for more details:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/

### Ordering Priority of URL Patterns

> When matching the specified patterns against an incoming request, the matching is done in the order in which the elements are declared. So the most specific matches patterns should come first and the most general should come last.
>
> There are multiple children to the http.authorizeRequests() method
>   each matcher is considered in the order they were declared.
>
> Patterns are always evaluated in the order they are defined. Thus it is important that more specific patterns are defined higher in the list than less specific patterns.

Read here for more details:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-security-interceptor

### Example 1

General use of WebSecurity `ignoring()` method omits Spring Security and none of Spring Security’s features will be available.
WebSecurity is based above HttpSecurity
(in an XML configuration you can write this: `<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>`).

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**")
        .antMatchers("/publics/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/publics/**").hasRole("USER") // no effect
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

WebSecurity in the above example lets Spring ignore `/resources/**` and `/publics/**`. Therefore the `.antMatchers("/publics/**").hasRole("USER")` in HttpSecurity is unconsidered.

> This will omit the request pattern from the security filter chain entirely. 
>   Note that anything matching this path will then have no authentication or authorization services applied and will be freely accessible.

### Example 2

Patterns are always evaluated *in order*. The below matching is invalid because the first matches every request and will never apply the second match:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN"):
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. In fact, securing the url to an image doesn't make much sense, if the image is public (e.g. the company logo on the page header).

Comment: Yes indeed. Another examples are JavaScript, CSS Resources, so all static Content that also could be cacheable. All Urls you mean make sense to be secured could you protect with Authentication and Authorization.

Comment: I'm wondering: what happens if with the same order priority, `WebSecurity` says `ignore` and `HttpSecurity` says `access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` for a specific path?

Comment: HttpSecurity is quite similar to the http namespace element. It allows configuring web based security for a certain selection (in this case all) requests.
WebSecurity is quite similar to any Security namespace elements that are for the web and that do not require a parent (i.e. security=none, debug, etc). It allows configuring things that impact all of web security.
See: http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/
For Explanation of Ordering Priority I have edited the previous Post.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the code you shared, if you had your static files i.e. CSS/JS etc in a folder called static then all your static resources will be added to the page whereas if you left out

```
web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/static/**");
```

none of your static resources will be loaded.

Spring Security is extremely powerful, Spring has great documentation so you should just go read about it fully appreciate/understand it.

Here is a 
[link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/introduction.html#what-is-acegi-security)

Comment: I'm not sure. All the images, css and js are loaded regardless of that instruction.

Comment: are you using Spring boot?

Comment: Sure. Every image, css and js  is in `resources/static`